# Pandas select rows passing some conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have two dataframe and having same column name with different rows I wanted to compare the columns both values and select rows from one the dataframe which are passing condition

A=

```
         data       P2      P0
       data2387  0.2810  0.5207
       data3549  0.3008  0.5203
       data3773  0.2602  0.5203
       data2087  0.0813  0.5203
```

B=

```
     P0        P2
    0.5207  0.030000
  1.028001  0.030001
  1.026004  0.030004
  1.024009  0.030009
    0.51    0.030016
```

output

```
   data        P0        P2
  data2387  0.2810  0.5207
  data3797  0.2667  0.5167
```

what I tried

`df=A[[(B['P0'] <= A['P0']) & (B['P2'] >= A['P2'])]]`

thank you

Comment: Do you want `A[B.P0.le(A.P0) | B.P2.gt(A.P2)]`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make use of [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method so that to make both `A` and `B` dataframes of same length

```
A=A.reindex(B.index)
```

or

```
B=B.reindex(A.index)
```

**Note:-** From above code use any one i.e either make changes in A or make change in B

Finally apply your boolean mask(as from your expected output you need to use `|` instead of `&`):-

```
df=A[(B['P0'] <= A['P0']) | (B['P2'] >= A['P2'])]
```

The above code give you your desired output

Comment: @anky thanks for your suggestion...cross joining destroys the original data maybe after reindexing we can fill values based on other df